# Why does existing `node_modules` break dependency resolution?

Tags: node.js, npm

*After* deleting my `package-lock.json` because of dependency issues, I ran `npm i` on my project.

Got:

```bash
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: project-name@1.131.4
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1101.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"0.1102.19" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"0.1102.19" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@11.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"11.2.14" from @angular/service-worker@11.2.14
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/service-worker
npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/service-worker@"^11.0.0 || ^11.2.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.19
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"0.1102.19" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/user/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

After deleting `node_modules`, all dependencies install with `npm i` (no force flags required)

Why do the contents of `node_modules`, which is meant to be overwritten, break dependency resolution? Shouldn't the list of dependencies I'm specifying in my `package.json` be followed by overwriting the contents of `node_modules`?

I know `node_modules` won't be overwritten every time you run `npm i`, but shouldn't it be if dependency resolution is breaking?

Comment: Uh.. I'm not breaking anything! Have you tried to delete the folder as well and run `npm install` again?

Comment: Haha don't take it personally. Cool username. I've already deleted the folder and `npm i` now works, which is what I'm confused about.

Comment: Glad it worked! Looking on the NPM website, the package-lock.json. It can [be found here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-lock-json). This page describes exactly what this file is for. :) It looks like it's some sort of dictionary for installed modules.

Comment: As mentioned at the start of the question, I deleted the `package-lock.json` before starting.